# Using Scanner to take input from two objects of the same class

Tags: java.util.scanner

I have a problem with functionality of my simple program I am making at the moment. I am trying to create two objects, each of them is asking user to provide a name and then choose from few options, by using `Scanner`. First object, monster of class `createMonster`, is asking user to provide information through Scanner. However, while creating second object `monster2` of class `createMonster`, program does not asking for user input.

Do I need to do some changes in my class `CreateScanner` or is it a bigger problem?

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomMonsterGenerator monster = new RandomMonsterGenerator();
        monster.createMonster();
        RandomMonsterGenerator monster2 = new RandomMonsterGenerator();
        monster2.createMonster();
    }
}
```

`RandomMonsterGenerator` code:

```
public class RandomMonsterGenerator {

    // Objects
    Attributes attr = new Attributes();
    CreateScanner createScanner = new CreateScanner();

    // Variables
    String monsterName;
    String attributesValues;
    int choice;

    // Main method for generating monster
    public void createMonster() {
        attr.generateAttributes();
        generateName();
        chooseClass();
        System.out.println("Generating random stats:");
        attributesValues = attr.toString();
        System.out.println(attributesValues);
        createScanner.closeScanner();
    }

    // Generating monster name
    private void generateName() {
        System.out.println("Name your monster: ");
        monsterName = createScanner.stringInput();
        System.out.println("Name of the monster: " + monsterName);
    }

    // Choosing a class
    private void chooseClass() {
        System.out.println("Class descriptions: ");
        System.out.println("Warrior has +2 to Strength and +2 to Condititon.");
        System.out.println("Thief has +2 to Dexterity and +2 to Charisma.");
        System.out.println("Mage has +2 to Intelligence and +2 to Wisdom.");
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        System.out.println("Choose your class from following options: ");
        System.out.println("Warrior, press '1'");
        System.out.println("Thief, press '2'");
        System.out.println("Mage, press '3'");
        choice = createScanner.intInput();
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                Warrior warrior = new Warrior(attr);
                System.out.println(monsterName + " is a warrior.");
                break;
            case 2:
                Thief thief = new Thief(attr);
                System.out.println(monsterName + " is a thief.");
                break;
            case 3:
                Mage mage = new Mage(attr);
                System.out.println(monsterName + " is a mage.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No option choosen.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`CreateScanner` code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateScanner {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String stringInput() {
        String input = "";
        if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            input = sc.nextLine();
        }
        return input;
    }
    public int intInput() {
        int input2 = 0;
        if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            input2 = sc.nextInt();
        }
        return input2;
    }
    public void closeScanner() {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, don't close the scanner until you're done with it. This closes the `System.in`
 as well and as soon as you do that you won't be getting anymore input. This is why it just skips over the second RandomMonsterGenerator input.

Second, only create one Scanner and pass it to your RandomMonsterGenerator as an argument. This keeps things simple.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    RandomMonsterGenerator monster = new RandomMonsterGenerator(scanner);
    RandomMonsterGenerator monster2 = new RandomMonsterGenerator(scanner);
}
```